# Submit same form with two action?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form to submit and send data to 2 pages via POST.

I have tried the code with javascript. One form submit is working but other submit is not working

```
<form id="add">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return Submit();">
</form>
```

javascript

```
function SubmitForm()
{
     document.forms['add'].action='filecreate.php';
     document.forms['add'].submit();
     document.forms['add'].action='filecreate.fr.php';
     document.forms['add'].submit();
     return true;
}
```

The first submission is not working but 2nd submission is working.

Comment: you can use ajax

Comment: call SubmitForm on onclick

Comment: <input type="submit" onclick="SubmitForm();">

Comment: You are probably better off either sending two AJAX requests, or to process the data in the same execution in PHP.

Comment: its a code error i am calling SubmitForm();

Comment: Qirel can you share me the code?

Answer (score 2):

Since you appear to send the exact same data to two different handlers, you can flip the coin - and say that you just submit one form, and process them both in `filecreate.php`.

As you are sending a form, you cannot send two separate forms in the same HTTP request - so you can either do them both through asynchronous methods, or process them both backend after the submission of *one* form.

Since you haven't shown any PHP code, I'm making some assumptions and writing some pseudo-code, but it should be enough to get you started.

So first off, set a static action-property to your form.

```html
<form id="add" action="filecreate.php">
   <input type="text" name="test">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you are sending it over POST, then you need to specify the method as well,

```html
<form id="add" action="filecreate.php" method="POST">
```

Then, in PHP, you can get both files executed if you include it to the other. Meaning, in your `filecreate.php`, you include the `filecreate.fr.php`. Once you do that, the contents of that file will be executed as well.

```php
<?php 
// Once you require the file, it will be executed in place
require "filecreate.fr.php";

// .. handle the rest of your normal execution here.
```

That said, if you are doing the very similar thing multiple times, just with different data, you may want to create functions for it instead - going with the DRY principle ("Don't Repeat Yourself"), you can probably create a function that handles the structure and processing, then send the data separately through that function.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<form id="add">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <input type="button" onclick="return SubmitForm();">
</form>

function SubmitForm()
{
 if(document.forms['add'].onsubmit())
 {
     document.forms['add'].action='filecreate.php';
     document.forms['add'].submit();
     document.forms['add'].action='filecreate.fr.php';
     document.forms['add'].submit();
 }
 return true;
}
```